# Load requirejs module's css dependency with webpack

Tags: javascript, css, requirejs, webpack

I am using [webpack](http://webpack.github.io) and I need to include some libraries built for [requirejs](http://requirejs.org).
Everything worked fine until one of the library declared a [css dependency](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css):

```
define(["css!./stylesheet.css"], function(){ \* module *\ });
```

Webpack has a [css loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) too, however it does not load them automatically as requirejs's one does. One must pipe the [css loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) to the [style loader](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader) to do so:

```
require("style!css!./stylesheet.css");
```

Is there any way to make the prior working? For example, can I overwrite the css loader for this particular library so that it is piped with the style loader ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a nice solution using `postLoaders`.

Adding

```
postLoaders: [
  { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style', include: path.join(__dirname, "pathTo/theLib") }
]
```

into the `module` property of the webpack config did the trick.